# How to add a method to a mock on scala

Tags: json, scala, mockito

I have a code like that:

```
class Object3 (
  param1: String
  param2: String
)

class Object1 (
  param1: String
  param2: Object2
) extends Message

class SampleClassSpec extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar {
  "A sender" should {
    "send a message" in {
      val client = mock[Client]
      var message = mock[Object1]
      var detail = mock[Object2]

      when(message.param2).thenReturn(detail)
      when(message.param2.toJson).thenReturn(detail.toJson) // give me NPE

      val sender = new Sender(client)
      sender.prepareandsend(message) // second NPE
      verify(client).send(message.param2.toJson.prettyPrint)
    }
  }
}
```

the problem is that I got NPE when I want to add the method to get formatted json, I don't want to send the whole Object1, just the Object3; I'm using spray.json._ for this.
if I remove the line that give me NPE, then I got a second NPE on "prepareandsend"

My question is how I can add this method toJson.prettyPrint to a mock?
Or maybe there is another way to do this. I'm a really beginner on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Scala, but I have worked with Mockito before.
It seems to me that the problem is that you haven't set any behavior for detail.
Since it's a mock as well, it doesn't have any behavior, so it won't return anything when you call detail.toJson

You should add some behavior to detail with

```
when(detail.toJson).thenReturn(/* your JSON code */)
```

Comment: i'm also a beginner, but for example can you tell me why if I put only .toSting it works? I didn't give any behavior as well.

Comment: If Scala is the same as Java then all classes inherit from the class Object by default which provides an implementation of .toString(), so that's why detail.toString works

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
when(param2.toJson).thenReturn(detail.toJson)
```

instead.

Alternatively, you can look into using Mockitos [DEEP_STUBS](https://idodevjobs.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/mockito-deep-stubs-example/) mechanism.

Comment: i tried it, same NPE. For now the quick solution was create Object1 with fake data and add it on prepareandsend()